# How to make TLS connection to RabbitMQ from python application

Tags: python, rabbitmq, paho, python-paho

I use RabbitMQ with Mqtt plugin. My docker-compose is like below:

```
loopback_users.guest = false
listeners.tcp = none
listeners.ssl.default = 5671
password_hashing_module = rabbit_password_hashing_sha512

# General
ssl_options.cacertfile = /etc/rabbitmq/cert/ca_certificate.pem
ssl_options.certfile   = /etc/rabbitmq/cert/server_certificate.pem
ssl_options.keyfile    = /etc/rabbitmq/cert/server_key.pem
ssl_options.verify     = verify_peer
ssl_options.fail_if_no_peer_cert  = true

# Web
management.ssl.port = 15672
management.ssl.cacertfile = /etc/rabbitmq/cert/ca_certificate.pem
management.ssl.certfile   = /etc/rabbitmq/cert/server_certificate.pem
management.ssl.keyfile    = /etc/rabbitmq/cert/server_key.pem
management.load_definitions = /etc/rabbitmq/definitions.json


# Mqtt plugin
mqtt.allow_anonymous = false
mqtt.listeners.ssl.default = 8883
mqtt.listeners.tcp.default = 1883
```

My certs are correct. Web works fine with security. So I want to connect to Rabbit from my Python application by TLS.

```
    PATH_CERT = '/<path>/server_certificate.pem'
    client = paho.Client()
    client.on_connect = on_connect
    client.on_publish = on_publish
    client.on_message = on_message
    client.username_pw_set(MQTT_USER, MQTT_PASSWORD)
    client.tls_set(ca_certs = PATH_CERT, tls_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2)
    client.tls_insecure_set(False)
    client.connect('my.domain.pl', 8883, 60)
    client.loop_forever()
```

But I got error:

```
File "/usr/lib/python3.8/ssl.py", line 1309, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1131)
```

Password, user and domain are correct. How could I solve problem with certyficate?
Does it pass the correct certificate in Python?

Answer (score 0):

These two options configure Erlang/RabbitMQ TLS to request a client certificate from your Python/Paho application, but you are not providing client certificates in your client application:

```
ssl_options.verify     = verify_peer
ssl_options.fail_if_no_peer_cert  = true
```